# Help Targeting element

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(".main").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("classA").toggleClass("classB");
    $(".secondary").toggleClass("classC").toggleClass("classD");
));

$(".secondary").click(function() {
    $(".secondary").toggleClass("classC").toggleClass("classD");
));
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="main"></div>

<div>
    <div class="secondary"></div>
    <table class="tbl"></table>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="secondary"></div>
    <table class="tbl"></table>
</div>
```

Currently it allows me to toggle class when each "secondary" element is clicked individually or change for all secondary when "main" is clicked. I need to add show/hide table in appropriate div when corresponding "secondary" or "main" is clicked. Having difficulty targetting. Tried but failed:

```
$(this).closest(".tbl").toggle();
```

Comment: You don't need to chain `.toggleClass()` calls. This works just as well: `$(this).toggleClass("classA classB");`

Comment: @Cybernate It's in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".secondary").click(function() {
    $(".secondary").toggleClass("classC").toggleClass("classD");
    $(this).parent().children(".tbl").toggle();
 //or this: $(this).next(".tbl").toggle();
));
```

Comment: Apparently i had another div around secondary... so .parent().parent() did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm exactly understanding what you're asking, but have a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/DQcSE/

Here's the source for that:

```
$(".main").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("classA classB");
    $(".secondary").each(toggleSecondary);
});

$(".secondary").click(toggleSecondary);

function toggleSecondary() {
    $(this).toggleClass("classC classD")
           .next('.tbl').toggle();
}
```

I've set up a function to generically handle toggling for a `.secondary`.  In the `.main` click handler, the main classes are toggled, and the `secondaryToggle()` function is invoked on each `.secondary`.  In the `.secondary` click handler, `secondaryToggle()` is invoked only on the clicked element.

`secondaryToggle()` toggles the classes of that element, and selects the next element (only if it has class `.tbl`) and toggles its visibility.

Note also that you need not call `.toggleClass()` for each class - you can pass it a space-separated list of classes toggle, much like you can do with `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`.